# ubuntu server no audio output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I need to deploy linux ubuntu servers (no desktop) with the ability to play audio files from command line.
After installing the ubuntu 12.04 server edition I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

and then added my user to the audio group

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio myusername
```

After these operations I opened amixer and did rise all outputs to 100% on.
The problem is that I still cannot have any audio output.
I know for sure that the audio card works since when I run lubuntu live 12.04 on the same pc I can hear the audio output.
Does anybody know what I'm missing to have the server edition play audio files?

EDIT:
Well I found out the problem was the "Simple mixer control 'PCM',0" was off and this was the reason why the audio was not working. The command

```
amixer -c 0 set 'PCM' 90% on
```

did solve my problem. Well at least I think in this post there are all the command needed to activate audio on an ubuntu server. To display the current audio levels just type

```
amixer
```

and finally, after 'PCM', it is important to check that 'Master' is 100% on:

```
amixer -c 0 set Master 100% on
```

Comment: Output from mplayer?

Comment: Thank you the problem was solved, I missed the [off] on PCM

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. Clearly sound was working on the system since I had no issues with games and `mpg123`, but I was unable to get any audio output from `mplayer`. I solved it in this simple way:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer2
```